# how to convert each PDF pages to individual images c#

Tags: c#

lots of free library available which can convert pdf to images.

```
   string file = "D:/test.pdf";
   string image = "D:\\test.png";

   try
   {
       GflAx.GflAxClass g = new GflAx.GflAxClass();
       g.EpsDpi = 150;
       g.Page = 1;
       g.LoadBitmap(file);
       g.SaveFormat = GflAx.AX_SaveFormats.AX_PNG;
       g.SaveBitmap(image);
       MessageBox.Show(this, "PDF to PNG conversion ended");
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       MessageBox.Show(this, "GflAx error: " + ex.Message);
   }
```

another free library like 
http://code.google.com/p/lib-pdf/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57100/Simple-and-Free-PDF-to-Image-Conversion

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42287/Convert-PDF-pages-to-image-files-using-the-Solid-F

i have 2 requirement like if my pdf file has 20 pages then library which i need to use that will generate 20 images for 20 pages...means one images for each pages at a time and save in folder those images.

another requirement is that if i send page no then it will generate the images only for that page...please guide me which library i need to used to fulfill my requirement.

thanks

Comment: i was trying to know how to iterate in all the pages of pdf file and save each page to images. i asked because i don't know how to do it...i search google but found no similar things. most of the good pdf lib is chargeable...please tell me is there any free library available which enable me to do this. thanks